# Calling lean() after findOneDocument vs lean() on returned document - Why is calling lean() on returned document not working?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the error I'm getting => "TypeError: apartment.lean is not a function"

In this code, I get an error which says lean() is not a function:

```
let apartment = await Apartment.findOne({
    'address.placeId':req.body.placeId,
    'address.apartmentNumber':req.body.apartmentNumber
});

if(apartment){
    //fetch references of pictures belonging to the apartment and send them back to the user
    const pictureReferences = fetchPictureReferences(apartment._id);
    let apartmentPoJo = apartment.lean();
    apartmentPoJo.pictures=[...pictureReferences];

    
    return res.status(200).json({msg:'Apartment Found',apartment:apartmentPoJo});
}
```

In that code, it runs fine, basically calling the lean() function right after the findOne() finishes:

```
let apartment = await Apartment.findOne({
    'address.placeId':req.body.placeId,
    'address.apartmentNumber':req.body.apartmentNumber
}).lean();

if(apartment){
    //fetch references of pictures belonging to the apartment and send them back to the user
    const pictureReferences = fetchPictureReferences(apartment._id);
    apartment.pictures=[...pictureReferences];

    
    return res.status(200).json({msg:'Apartment Found',apartment});
}
```

**Can you let me know why they're different ? I'm assuming that the findOne() function returns a document. Whether I execute it on the spot or on the new variable that I created no ?**

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `lean` is only a method of the `Model` (or `Query`) class. The returned `Document` class DOES NOT have the `lean` method.

Models and Documents are both Mongoose classes, but they're not the same. Calling a **Query** method (like findOne) on a **Model** returns an **instance of a Document**.

[Document Methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html)

[Model Methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html)

[Query Methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) (most of [these methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) are a part of the **Model** class)

```js
const findApartment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { apartmentNumber, placeId } = req.body;
    if (!apartmentNumber || !placeId) throw String("You must supply a valid apartment and id!"); 
  
    /* 
       Using the Apartment model, we invoke Query methods "findOne" and "lean".
       
       The result of these two queries is a document instance transformed into 
       a plain Javascript object (a plain object where Mongoose virtuals are removed) 
       
       If you ran the query without invoking "lean", then "findOne" 
       would return an instance of a Document, which contain the methods
       associated with Documents -- as shown above, the Document class does not 
       contain the "lean" method.
    */
    const apartment = await Apartment.findOne({
      'address.placeId': placeId,
      'address.apartmentNumber': apartmentNumber
    }).lean();
    if (!apartment) throw String("Unable to locate the apartment with that address!");

    return res.status(200).json({msg: 'Apartment Found', apartment });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(404).json({ msg: err.toString() });
  }
};
```

The confusing part may come from the fact that Model and Document may share the same method names (like populate: [D](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate), [M](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.populate)), but they're not the same.

More info about **lean** can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html).

Comment: Thanks, very clear! 

Makes me wonder again how methods are being called in javascript. I always thought that the methods we call in sequence are in fact properties of the returned object of the previous method called. 

Taking example of a.b().c() entails, 'a' calling method b which is a property of a. and then calling method c, which is a property of the object returned by b.

In this situation, a.b().c() is in fact 'a' calling method b which is a property of a and then calling method c, which is ALSO a property of a.

Comment: Mongoose is most likely using [prototype chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#using_prototypes_in_javascript), where: `b` is a method of `a`, and `c` is a method `b` and `d` is a method of `c` and so on. This way, you can compose methods in (almost) any order: `Model.findOne().populate().select()` or `Model.findOne().select().populate()` and so on. If you're really interested, then I'd recommend diving into the [Mongoose source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/tree/master/lib).

Comment: Yeah indeed, I just dove a little bit further, seems it's kind of like a middleware function where the new method alters the prototype of the "Query" object and then passes it on. In that case, every method is altering the Query prototype and returning the Query Object for the next function to keep altering the Query.
Eventually what executes this Query is the .exec function which returns a promise that is thenable. It is less visible in the code I wrote which made it confusing as I'm not showing a .exec() call. >> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await?